# Separation of concerns in Node.js app and dealing with load across different processes

Tags: node.js, architecture, layer

I have a Node application which persists data to a MongoDB database. Most of this data is in hand, such as data for the `User` collection. However, the application also has the concept of `Website` collection, and for this collection, data must first be downloaded from somewhere before it is saved.

I am wondering how I should separate the above concerns in my application. At the service layer, I have things like `User` and `Website`. They provide basic CRUD operations. At completely the opposite end of the spectrum, there is a user interface whereby uses can input a website URL. Somewhere between this UI and the application persisting the data to MongoDB (the service layer), the application must make a request to this URL to gather some data. Once the data has been fetched, the `Website` service will persist it.

Potentially, there could be thousands of these URLs entered at once, and I do not want to bring down the Node process that handles the web server due to load issues. Therefore I think it would be a good idea to abstract the work out to a different process and use some sort of messaging bus to tie the application together.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've decomposed system correctly -and have created that separation at the persistence "service" layer-, but I'd take this separation a bit further by moving toward a distributed system architecture (i.e. SOA / micro-services).

The initial step of building a distributed system is identifying each of the functions necessary to meet the overall business goal of the application and mapping these to service endpoints.  Each loosely coupled service endpoint will then serve a small isolated job/function and it will act as an abstraction for that business goal.

By continuing the separation of responsibilities all the way to the service endpoint you **create small independent boundaries for scalability, throughput, fault tolerance, security, deployment, etc.**

For example -RESTfully speaking-, this might mean service endpoints for both Users (e.g. `/users/{userid}`) and Websites (e.g. `/websites/{websiteid|url}`)... and perhaps an additional Resource to maintain the relationship/link between the two (e.g. `/users/{userid}/userwebsites : {websiteid:1234,url:blah.com`).

This separation would mean you can handle the website processing responsibility independently, which would have a number of benefits -beyond just handling the different load characteristics-.